# Avoid reinstalling package

Tags: apt, aptitude

How to avoid reinstalling a package in `apt install` and `apt-get install`

In two cases

One case is I have `firefox` 75 installed and the repositories have `firefox` 76

Second case is I have `firefox` 76 installed, and the repositories have `firefox` 76 too

I need a way to avoid reinstall in one case and a second way to avoid reinstall in the second case

For example a switch `--no-reinstall` and a switch `--no-upgrade`

Comment: that's not a reinstallation you're describing, that's an upgrade, from `apt`'s perspective: it won't install a package if it finds the same or lower version in a repository.

Comment: OK, so if `apt` is totally unable to reinstall an existing package, I will just need a way to avoid upgrading if the package exists

Comment: OK! By the way, reinstallations are basically never automatically done, only on user request (`apt --reinstall install packagename` will do it, `apt install packagename` will just tell you that hey, you've already got that installed, nothing to do).

Answer (score 0):

You can tell your package manager that you want to really keep the version of a package; see `man dpkg`, scroll down to `--set-selections`; what you want is the `hold` state, so, in your example:

```
echo firefox hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

`aptitude` is a nice TUI that can do this for you; you find the installed package you want to hold and type the magic key (I think it was <kbd>=</kbd>).

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the reply. I have `apt install firefox`, I need it to reinstall nothing, how do I do?

Comment: If there's no update to the firefox package, you don't have to do anything. Your quesiton is about "if there *was* an update available, how do I tell my system that I don't *want* to update it", and my answer explains how.

Comment: Yeah but I don't understand the reply

Comment: You might find `apt-mark` easier than `dpkg --set-selections`.

Comment: OK, so I should do `apt-mark firefox && apt install firefox`

Comment: why would you install it if you already have it?

Comment: @aac you missed the `hold` verb, so `apt-mark hold firefox`.  btw, successfully installing or upgrading a package resets the hold status, so you need to `apt-mark hold` it again.   i.e. install/upgrade first, then hold it.   I do this all the time with packages that I don't want to be auto-upgraded (firefox is one of them, as are chromium, nvidia-kernel-dkms, zfs-dkms, linux-image-amd64 and several others), that I only want to upgrade manually.

Comment: Okay, maybe editing the answer or posting a new one